# Using subprocess.run in nuitka-complied exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, subprocess, nuitka

When using a subprocess to run a PowerShell file, a terminal (cmd) window pops open and closes real fast.
I manged to slow down using a video and read the contents.

\network\path
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows Directory.

This is is the sample code

```
def query_user(username_: str) -> int:
    username_ = username_.strip()
    """"checks the user status in the domain, such as locked, disabled, expired, password expired"""
    comd = """
function Get-UserStatus {
    param (
        [string]$user
    )

    $userObj = Get-AdUser "$user" -Properties LockedOut,PasswordLastSet,Enabled,AccountExpirationDate,logonHours

    if (-not $userObj.Enabled) {
        return "1"
    }
    elseif (-not ($userObj.logonHours -contains 255)) {
        return "5"
    }
    elseif ($userObj.AccountExpirationDate -lt (Get-Date)) {
        return "3"
    }
    elseif ($userObj.PasswordLastSet -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)) {
        return "4"
    }
    elseif ($userObj.LockedOut) {
        return "2"
    }
    else {
        return "0"
    }
}

Get-UserStatus({user_o})
""".replace("user_o", username_)
    file_pa = "c:\\quick_run.ps1"
    with open(file_pa, "w") as fo:
        fo.write(comd)
    results = run(["powershell.exe", "-NoProfile", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", "-File", file_pa],
                  capture_output=True, text=True, creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW, shell=False).stdout.strip()
    try:
        unlink(file_pa)
    except (PermissionError, FileNotFoundError):
        pass

    if results == "2":
        Thread(target=lambda: run(["powershell", "-Command", f"Unlock-ADAccount -Identity {username_}"],
                                  shell=True, creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW), daemon=True).start()
        config.tasks.append(lambda: messagebox.showwarning("Unlocked user", f"User {username_} was unlocked"))
        config.tasks.append(lambda: copy_clip("Unlocked User"))
        return 0
    return int(results)
```

While when launching it uncompiled no terminal window is popping open, any help will be greatly appricated!

I'm not 100% sure it's a nuitka issue, but when uncompiled I get no terminal.
The function is being ran from a thread

I tried adding & exit after calling the file - nothing changed
I expect the exe to not launch a terminal window when running the function.
Side note, im compiling gui app (tkinter) and use `--windows-disable-console` when compiling it.